# Better way to cbind newly calculated column and quickly naming output

Tags: r, cbind

I've finally lost my habit of loops in R. Basically usually calculating new columns, and then doing calculations and aggregations on these new columns.
But I have a question regarding cbind which I use for adding columns.

Is there a better way than using bind for things like this?

Naming this new column always is done by me in this tedious way... Anything cleverer/simpler out there?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")
GSPC <- cbind(GSPC, lag(Cl(GSPC), k=1))   #Doing some new column calculation
names(GSPC)[length(GSPC[1,])] <- "Laged_1_Cl"   #Naming this new column
GSPC <- cbind(GSPC, lag(Cl(GSPC), k=2))
names(GSPC)[length(GSPC[1,])] <- "Laged_2_Cl" 
tail(GSPC)
```

** EDITED **
Roman Luštrik added a great solution in comments below.

```
GSPC$Laged_3_Cl <- lag(Cl(GSPC), k=3)
tail(GSPC)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `GSPC$newvar <- lag(Cl(GSPC), k=1)` also work?

Comment: Yes.
Thanks for helping.
Any chance you could post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of adding new variables to a data.frame is through the `$` operator. Help page (`?"$"`) shows common usage in the form of

```
x$i <- value
```

Where `i` is the new variable name and `value` are its associated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the new column on the left side of the assignment like so:

```
exdat <- data.frame(lets = LETTERS[1:10],
                    nums = 1:10)

exdat$combo <- paste0(exdat$lets, exdat$nums)
```